# Use BeautifulSoup to extract table formatted with <br/> tags

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have an HTML table formatted like this:

```
<p>
  <strong>A</strong>1<br/>
  <strong>B</strong>2<br/>
</p>
```

I want to use BeautifulSoup to read this into a dictionary of the format `{'A': '1', 'B': '2'}`. What's the best way to do this? I managed to do something hacky:

```
g = list(soup.find('p').childGenerator())
# g == [<strong>A</strong>, '1', <br/>, <strong>B</strong>, '2', </br>]
table = {g[3*i]: g[3*i+1] for i in range(int(len(g)/3))}
```

But this feels vulnerable to slight variations in the table's formation. Is there a better or more canonical way?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the content you posted here is dummy, I'm unsure of your exact requirement. Here is the code you need as per your requirement.

```
text_content = [x for x in soup.text.split('\n') if x]
some_dict = {}
i = 0
for abc in soup.find_all('strong'):
    some_dict[abc.text] = text_content[i].replace(abc.text, '')
    i += 1

print(some_dict)

>> {'A': '1', 'B': '2'}
```